# Dynamically enabling/disabling BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, dynamic, static, broadcastreceiver

I have a BroadcastReceiver statically registered in my app's manifest file with attributes 
`"enabled"` and `"exported"` set to true and an intent filter filtering the `android.intent.PHONE_STATE` intent. However, in some cases I need to dynamically disable/unregister this `BoradcastReceiver` and then register/enable it again. I know about the way to do it by using `PackageManager` and set the `"ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED"` and `"ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED"` for the `BroadcastReceiver` component but isn't there any other way to do it? And if I dynamically register the `BroadcastReceiver` would it work if my application is not running or after a reboot? Because when it is registered statically it works fine in such cases.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can register it dynamically. You have to use `intent-filter` in `manifest` and within inten-filer you have to declare `action` by which this broadcast receiver would invoke.For detailed information visit following links http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/intent-filter-element.html  and http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBroadcastReceiver/article.html#ownreceiver.

Comment: You are talking about a statical way to register it. Dynamical means at an application runtime by putting some code in activity.